# Using Json in p5.Js: Call json variable with blanck spaces from api

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, p5.js

I cant acces this json data:

```
{
"Meta Data": {
    "1. Information": "Intraday (1min) open, high, low, close prices and volume",
    "2. Symbol": "MSFT",
    "3. Last Refreshed": "2019-01-24 16:00:00",
    "4. Interval": "1min",
    "5. Output Size": "Compact",
    "6. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
},
"Time Series (1min)": {
    "2019-01-24 16:00:00": {
        "1. open": "106.2300",
        "2. high": "106.2600",
        "3. low": "106.1700",
        "4. close": "106.1700",
        "5. volume": "236047"
    }
```

From my p5.js project because of the blanck spaces between words **"Time Series (1min)"**, this is my p5.js script.

```js
function setup() {
  
  loadJSON("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=5min&apikey="+stockApi, gotData, 'jasonp');
}

function gotData(data){
  print(data);
}
```

So I want to know how to acces **data.Time Series (1min).2019-01-24 16:00:00.high**, somenthing like that.

Answer (score 0):

Simple - use array notation:

```
data["Time Series (1min)"]["2019-01-24 16:00:00"]["2. high"]
```

Comment: Tried that but chrome gave me this error:

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '2019-01-24 16:00:00' of undefined
    at gotData (api.js:14)
    at p5.min.js:3

Comment: That's your Promise not working - the code I posted will work perfectly. I'll make a demonstration.

Comment: Well it works fine with **data["Meta Data"]**, but not with the others like **data["Time Series (1min)"]**